# GDAL's -a_ullr switch - cell centers or outer edges?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I am using gdal_translate to extract a NetCDF out to tiff. In the [gdal_translate documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html), there is an option `-a_ullr` to define the upper-left and lower-right corners (bounds) of the grid. Are these the cell centers of those grid cells, or the outer edges of the grid itself?

Comment: I don't know, but you could quickly test this by running it and checking in a GIS program. My guess is that it's the absolute bounds, not pixel centers, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the suggestion by @Jon. Let's give it a try.

- Sample: A single cell, 1000m x 1000m, centered at (0, 0)

This cell is shown as green (value 200) on `Dummy1x1_BYTE` layer.

[image]

- `gdal_translate -a_ullr 0 0 1000 -1000` returned an orange cell on a new layer `Dummy1x1_BYTE_ullr`.

This orange cell is set to Upper Left = (0, 0) and Lower Right (1000, -1000).

As @Jon has said. Yes, -a_ullr sets coordinates of corner points.

Answer (score 1):

Per Jon's suggestion, I tried something similar to Kazuhito. Here was my NetCDF input:

```
NC_GLOBAL#XORIG=-130
NC_GLOBAL#YORIG=22.5
NC_GLOBAL#XCELL=0.03999999910593033
NC_GLOBAL#YCELL=0.03999999910593033
NC_GLOBAL#NCOLS=1751
NC_GLOBAL#NROWS=751
```

I calculated the Max X/Y values as such:

```
max lon: -130 + (0.03999999910593033 * 1751) = -59.96000156551599217
max lat: 22.5 + (0.03999999910593033 * 751) = 52.53999932855367783
```

I used gdal_translate to move from NetCDF to Tiff using this switch:

```
-a_ullr -130 52.53999932855367783 -59.96000156551599217 22.5
```

Then, I zoomed way in and dropped some point markers on top of the raster:

[image: The lower left]

[image: The upper right]

The rasters are mostly a background value of 0, drawn as black in those screenshots. The labeled points come out right on the corners of the raster, so it appears the GDAL's -a_ullr option is using the outer boundaries of the grid, and not cell centers.

Also, I should note that the cell size is unchanged out to 17 significant digits (decimal degrees), so assuming the cell size is the extent divided by the number of rows/columns, then the output is true to the input.